# Error message saying my directory has a syntax error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, directory

I added a bit of code to my pygame project and then I tried to run it. I got this error.

```
>>> & C:/Users/shado/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe "c:/Users/shado/coding - PYTHON/schoolgame/MyNewGame.py"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/Users/shado/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe "c:/Users/shado/coding - PYTHON/schoolgame/MyNewGame.py"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I CTRL + Z'd the code I wrote, but the problem persisted. The carrot is pointing to the ampersand in the error message, by the way.

Comment: What is your code? How are you running your code?

Comment: The triple equals suggest you're already in a python shell, type `quit()` and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because you are running the command in the Python Shell. Try running this command:

```
quit()
```

And then running the earlier command:

```
& C:/Users/shado/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe "c:/Users/shado/coding - PYTHON/schoolgame/MyNewGame.py"
```